# Getting the Gradle core plugin error and i don't know what to do

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, plugins, android-gradle-plugin

- What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.5.0', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.5.0')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Google
  MavenRepo
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository

i want to run the app on android emulator but this error keeps coming no matter how much i try